# How to SetOnClicklistener in base adapter for listview in android ?

Tags: android, listview

i have trying to set the click listener in base adapter for my listview 
which is from server i have use this following code:

My getview in base adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_curr, null);

        holder.tv_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        holder.tv_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
        holder.relative = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative);

        Nav_List current=data.get(position);
        holder.tv_title.setTypeface(customfont);
        holder.tv_title.setText(current.getTitle());
        holder.tv_id.setText(current.getDes());


        holder.relative.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.relative.setTag(position);

        return view;
    }

}
```

My on click:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int pos = (Integer) view.getTag();
        Object object = getItem(pos);
        Nav_List beanclass = (Nav_List) object;

        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.relative:

//                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked :" + beanclass.getSku(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent in = new Intent(context,Baby_Cat.class);
                in.putExtra("Id",beanclass.getDes());
                context.startActivity(in);

                break;
        }


    }
```

But there is throwing error in onclick(). Error is below

```
10-07 11:47:26.245 15371-15371/com.kamalaminfo.asm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.kamalaminfo.asm, PID: 15371
                                                                     java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.kamalaminfo.asm.Getter_Setter.Nav_List
                                                                         at com.kamalaminfo.asm.Adapter.DrawerListAdapter.onClick(DrawerListAdapter.java:80)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5233)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21211)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

please help me in find the problem

Note: This same coding is working fine in another listview thats y i am confusing

Comment: use data.get(pos) instead of getItem(pos)

Comment: Object object = getItem(pos); is making a mess . Get item from your list directly like beanclass=data.get(pos)

Comment: Thank you its working fine.....

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like the casting of an Integer.
It might that your object isn't actually the class you cast it to. I think it might be the Integer it says in the error. Maybe you get the wrong item?

Try if you can go getClass on the object and print what it is. Then you see which class it is.

I personally would use, instead of "this" in the onClickListener I would write new onClickListener () and implement the methods and program whatever needed after clicking in there. If that is possible for you. Like

```
holder.relative.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener (){ 

    //methods onClick to be implemented
}
```